# How do I interpret the piece of code encircled in red in the image attached

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment using jupyter notebook with pre-written code. I came across some lines in the code that I couldn't understand (the ones circled in red in the attached image).

What does `'%4.0f' % (uR)` do in the code?

[image]

Comment: It's Python's (old) percentage formatting operator.  See e.g. [here](https://pyformat.info/), Since Python 3.6, [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) are an easier way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old school (python 2) way of printing floating points up to some specified precision. If you are familiar with other languages like C/C++, you will easily get that `print('%4.0f' % uR)` just prints the value of variable `uR` with fractional part approximated up to 4 digits.

In python 3.6 and later, you can just do this: `print(f"{uR:.4f}")`